# mysql assign list of values to foreign key pair

Tags: mysql, list, foreign-keys, unique-values

My question has to do with structuring my database

Basically, I have 20+ tables all with 10+ million records of various things. I, however, am not sure what to do with the following information

I have an overarching Id, main_id, that is associated with multiple sub ids, sub_id. However, the sub_ids are not unique to the main_id so;

```
+---------+--------+
| main_id | sub_id |
+---------+--------+
|       1 |      1 |
|       1 |      2 |
|       1 |      3 |
|       1 |      4 |
|       2 |      1 |
|       2 |      3 |
|       2 |      4 |
+---------+--------+
```

is a possibility.

this is fine because in the assignment of this unique pair i have to assign other values to other columns.

my problem comes in that one of the 'fields' for this unique pair, can have multiple values AND there is not necessarily a value at all for that field for every unique pair.
thus i currently have a table that's similar to this:

```
+---------+--------+------------+
| main_id | sub_id | problem_id |
+---------+--------+------------+
|       1 |      1 | NULL       |
|       1 |      2 | 1,2        |
|       1 |      3 | 2          |
|       1 |      4 | NULL       |
|       2 |      1 | 1          |
|       2 |      3 | 5          |
|       2 |      4 | 5,2        |
+---------+--------+------------+
```

except, i tried to have a row for every "problem_id" because I want to be able to do queries based on the individual values contained in the field.

Note that Main_id and sub_id are both foreign keys.

Comment: I think you should move the `problem_id` to another table with `main_id/sub_id` as a FK to the above table and a `problem_id` that holds exactly one problem (integer). The problem_table would have two rows for `main_id/sub_id=1/2` with problem_id 1 and 2 and no row for `1/1`.

Comment: thats exactly what I actually have now, in that i have two rows for main_id/sub_id = 1/2 and none for 1/1, but that doesn't allow for a primary key because the only natural key is all three columns.